# How to make sure expressjs start correctly at first run before running it forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, forever

I have a server using `expressjs` and the forever package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to keep the server always running.

I have a problem: when the server starts, it should be off if there is any config wrong, but the forever package always restarts it. How to make sure the server starts correctly (can be off at first run) and run forever if the config is right?

*The config I mentioned is gotten from AWS*

Comment: Can you add some code, How are you adding config? You can create a shell script that stops all the forever processes when there is an issue with the config.

Comment: Wouldn't you start it first without forever to make sure the config is correct and when it is fully ready for production (config has been fully tested), then you kill the running server and run it with forever for production.  At least that's how I built my program that uses forever.  I was forced into this because debugging the server never wanted to be run under forever anyway.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I just run `forever server.js`, and the config I mentioned is config is gotten from AWS

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you, but what happens if the config is gotten from AWS

Comment: Well, you DO have to test your server first anytime you get a new or different config right?

Comment: yes, need to test the server first when another server version is deployed

Comment: So, test first without forever and then when testing complete deploy with forever.

Comment: Well, I agree with @jfriend00, generally the config is tested before running a server in prod env. This is something that is being followed by most of the people, however, if your scenario is very specific which is not, you can follow the way jfriend00 explained.

Comment: @jfriend00 @ApoorvaChikara because the config exists inside `server.js` code, how to test them without starting `server.js` or I need to separate the config to another file and run something like `node config.js && forever server.js`

Comment: Well, I don't quite understand your deployment or how you get your config or how it is applied to your server (since there's nothing in your question about that except that is somehow comes from AWS), but `node server.js` will run your server without forever.

Comment: @jfriend00 I use gitlab ci and terraform to deploy the server, do you think I can run `node server.js` at gitlab ci before running terraform?